# Not able to fetch default parameter flag or value using getProcedureColumns function from DatabaseMetaData

Tags: java, database, oracle, stored-procedures

I am need either default value or default value specific flag for the parameter of a stored procedure in oracle database via java.

i am using getProcedureColumns method to get the default parameter details by passing the procedure name as below.
however, this is giving result at null.

```
ResultSet rs = con.getMetaData().getProcedureColumns(null, "SCHEMA", "PROCEDURE_NAME", null);
System.out.println("COLUMN_DEF:"+rs.getString("COLUMN_DEF"));
output
-------
COLUMN_DEF:null
```

Following is my stored procedure syntax.

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE  PROCEDURE_NAME
(
player_name IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'hero',
goals OUT NUMBER,
league OUT VARCHAR2
) AS

what is the reason that it does not give me the default value output?
what should be the solution?

I have tried checking in all_agrguments table and i can see that defaulted flag is Y for the default parameter which i have specified. however, i do not want to do any additional queries on db. i want to achieve this using above java method getProcedureColumns from java.sql pkg.